# Laravel Product Brands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a category page.

```
$page = SubCategory::FindOrFail($id);
$products = $page->products;
```

I'm returning a view and showing all products related to the category.

I'm trying to create a filter and view all brands which are associated to the products returned in the category.

I could create a

```
$page = SubCategory::FindOrFail($id);
$products = $page->products;
$brands = array();

foreach($products as $p){
    foreach($brands as $b){
        if(!in_array($p->brand->id,$brands)){
            $brands[] = $p->brand->id;
        }
    }
}
```

However I feel there could be a more eloquent way of doing it.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want all the brands that are linked to the products in `$products` or just the ID's?

Comment: does brands have a seperate table? is there a relationship? because currently i only see a empty array. Or is there a column on products with the brand name? or a brand_id , please give a bit more info

Comment: Apologies guys, yes products are related to brands by a brand_id in the products table but I was going to extend the above array to include the brand name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the id's of every brand that belongs to the product, you could do this:

```
$brandIds = $products->pluck('brand_id'); // assuming brand_id is the foreign key
```

If you also want the brand objects, you could do this:

```
$brands = Brand::whereIn('id', $brandIds)->get();
```

or eager load them:

```
$products = $page->products()->with('brand')->get();
$brands = $products->pluck('brand');
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I totally forgot about the pluck method! That's helped alot and I'll use that moving forward.